# Core Data sortDescriptor with diacritics results in strange behaviour

Tags: swiftui, core-data, swiftui-list

I have a standard Core Data setup with multiple sortDescriptors

```
func getPilots() -> [PilotEntity] {
        let request = PilotEntity.fetchRequest()
        let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isSelf", ascending: false)
        let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isFavourite", ascending: false)
        let tertiarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor, secondarySortDescriptor, tertiarySortDescriptor]
        
        do {
            return try fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error Fetching PilotEntity. \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
```

I am using the `PilotEntity` in the SwiftUI List. I have noticed a strange behaviour when the `name` contains diacritics. When updating the `PilotEntity` the list containing names with diacritics are momentarily reshuffled (index 9 is at index 7 and then jumps at 9 where it should be). When the diacritics are removed, the behaviour stops.

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples of the value of `name` and show how they are ordered? "index 9 is at index 7 and then jumps at 9" is unclear.

Comment: "Beránek John" displayed in console as ""Ber\U00e1nek John" is momentarily at index 7 instead of "Berger Joe" when navigating back from child view. The `PilotEntity` gets updated `onDisappear`

Comment: have you thought about storing a non-diacritic version of the name for sorting and searching?

Comment: I have, I have fixed this by using selector in the sort descriptor `NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))`

Answer (score 0):

I have added selector to the sort descriptor `NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))` to handle the diacritics. This has stopped the unexpected behaviour in the List view.